# Latex Code for Symbol

Tags: symbols

Could someone please help me with the Latex code for the symbol below?:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The symbol you are searching for is: `\nleq`

Found via: http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: You can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863) as I did in my edit.

Comment: Thanks, I'm not used to the TeX.sx markup yet :-)

Comment: The `\nleq` symbol requires `\usepackage{amssymb}`

Answer (score 1):

Another way (the original way before `amssymb`) is `\not\leq`